# Settext on a text view is crashing if used with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am downloading a text file which is approximately 2 MB containing text. When I download it I am trying to show it to user with `settext` method.
If I apply `txt.setText()` directly in my app, the app becomes so slow so I declared settext in AsyncTask but my app is getting crashed. I need fast method to set the text which I am downloading.
Code:

```
private class textviewLoader extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
  String msg;
  public textviewLoader(String txtToLoad) {
    msg=txtToLoad;
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    dataLoaded.setText(msg);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Logcat:

```
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):                java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:5054)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1003)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4358)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10508) 
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at android.widget.TextView.invalidateRegion(TextView.java:4708)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at android.widget.TextView.invalidateCursor(TextView.java:4651)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:7649)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:9411)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:979)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:688)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:588)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:110)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:121)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:302)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3782)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3652)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:100)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3627)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at com.dummy.SettingsActivity$textviewLoader.doInBackground(SettingsActivity.java:140)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at com.dummy.SettingsActivity$textviewLoader.doInBackground(SettingsActivity.java:1)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-03 09:36:44.930: E/AndroidRuntime(6940):     ... 5 more
```

Comment: Post your code and your logcat

Comment: You may setting the text in doInBackground() which will cause force close... better way is set text in  onPostExecute()..

Comment: you should not define UI changes in doinbackground..try to use onpostexecute()

Answer (score 3):

make sure you are not using the setText() method in doInBackground of Async Task.
Becasue you can't do the UI operation inside background thread.
You should call setText() inside onProgressUpdate or onPostExecute

Answer (score 1):

As @Ayaanp said you cannot use "`setText()` method in `doInBackground` of `Async Task`". If you want to use any UI operation inside `doInBackground` you should use `runOnUIThread` for example:

```
    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Loading Please Wait");
    }

     protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
     {
         // write downloading code....
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
         {
              public void run() 
              {
                 dataLoaded.setText(msg); //after downloading you could also use this setText() in onPostExecut() Method without the use of runOnUIThread().  

              }
         });
     }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(pd.isShowing())
        {
            pd.dismiss();
        }

   }
```

and you are done :) Now background task will execute successfully...

Comment: Ok I dont know its working or not..Still its making me to wait for a long time.Is there any way to show a ProgressDialog from the service on the Activity from where I called the service??

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update UI from any other thread except the Main Thread.

```
@Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    dataLoaded.setText(msg);
    return null;
  }
```

`setText(msg)` is upgrading the UI which should be run from the Main thread only. 
Do this in `onPostExecute()` method of AsyncTask. This method runs on Main Thread. **(You don't have to call runOnUIThread() in postExecute())**

Alternatively, you can call `publishProgress()` in doInBackground which calls the `onProgressUpdate()` method of the AsyncTask. You can use these methods for UI updations.

```
private class textviewLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String msg;

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

        dataLoaded.setText(msg);// Either update UI here
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
    public textviewLoader(String txtToLoad) {
        msg = txtToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        publishProgress();//This calls the onProgressUpdate() method
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dataLoaded.setText(msg);// Either update UI here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping this will solve your problem try using runonUIthread whenever you want to update the main UI thread`

```
onPostExecute() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                  txt.setText();  

                }
            });
}`
```

Comment: Where? I n AsyncTask?

Comment: In Async Task's  onPostExecute() Method